# WordPress custom post - add dynamically meta boxes

Tags: custom-post-types, visual-editor

I want build an custom editor for my custom post type in WordPress. I'm able to add multiple tinymce editor to the post type, but I want this dynamically.

I'd like admin users to be able to create and remove additional meta box fields as needed.

The admin user should be able to click a button (or select from a drop-down menu) that will add additional new metabox with an tinymce editor.

How would you arrange this?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Strangely plugins are off-limit here, even though that's what Wordpress is all about to many of us. I have to highly recommend the use of [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for this job. It has a built-in Wordpress/wysiwyg editor etc, and I'm very happy to talk you through the setup if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with Advanced Custom Fields (Pro). You can create dynamic repeat boxes with this plugin

Comment: Yep, it's pretty awesome huh? Well worth the pro version. It basically unlocks Wordpress as a 'surface' developer, I reckon.